# Auto Minify files on publishing SharePoint hosted app

Tags: javascript, css, sharepoint-hosted-app, schema

I have created SharePoint Hosted app with some list, scripts and css. Now I want to minify my files. Can we automate **minification** of files on deploying or on publishing?

Also can we apply minification only on publishing of app not on Deploying app?

Comment: Look at the Microsoft AJAX minifier, http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/. I've used it before in build activities to minify assets that would be deployed as part of a wsp, should still hold true for apps.

Comment: +1 for oldskool but still great EXE tools, my favorite for string replacements (in any file) is [FART.EXE](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) More complex templating with 40 year old [M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) As for minifying, it is usually done in the built process kicked off by your IDE with [Uglify2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) Debugging minified JS files you do with [SourceMaps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)